# Notation of the inner/dot product of many vectors

Tags: notation, inner-products

Operators like the summation operator and product operator when applied to a set of $n$ numbers defines a single operation such as adding or multiplying them all together. In general there is a nice representation.

Im wondering if its possible to have an operator which defines the dot product of many vectors.

i.e. instead of writing the dot product of many vectors as:
$$x_1\cdot x_2,...,\cdot x_N$$
does there exist a nicer notation of say (im just making this up)
$$\Psi_{i=1}^N x_i$$

which represents the above?

Comment: Notation aside, how do you even *define* "the dot product of many vectors" (where "many" is "more than $2$")? For instance, in $\Bbb{R}^2$, what is $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)\cdot(e,f)$?

Comment: @Blue The true underlying question is in reference to trying to find an operator which can define a set of multiple summation operators which enter in multiplicatively for  $$\sum_{a} \sum_b ...\sum_z x_{ia}x_{ib}... x_{iz}$$ I'm really trying to think of a way to define what we see on a decision tree. Maybe I should close this question and open another

Comment: @Blue I see the problem with what im doing. I was thinking what you suggested is just $$ace+bdf$$ this is incorrect but it is admittedly what I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you suggest on the elements of a set, such as a set of vectors, the set must be closed under the operation in question. Real numbers are closed under the operations of addition and multiplication so we can speak of repeated addition and repeated multiplication in that context. But the set of vectors is not closed under the dot-product operation, so repeated dot products do not make much sense in that context.